# Load Data from mysql to Ionic

Tags: mysql, ionic-framework, ionic3

Hi Developpers i am working in projet where i need to load data from database and show it in the page in ionic , i didn't found any problem but it didn't work too 
here is the page of getting data from database

```
    <?php
include("db.php");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

        $query = "select * from etudiant";
        $result = $db->query($query);

        $res['etudiant'] = [];

        while ($etud = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $res['etudiant'][] = $etud;
        }

        echo json_encode($res);
```

and this is the component page

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPage, NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';

import {EtudiantProvider} from "../../providers/etudiant/etudiant";


@IonicPage()
@Component({
    selector: 'page-etudiant',
    templateUrl: 'etudiant.html',
})
export class EtudiantPage {

    public isSearchbarOpened = false;

    etudiant:String;
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, NavParams: NavParams, public  etudiantProvider: EtudiantProvider) {
    }

    ngOnInt() {
        this.etudiantProvider.getEtudiant().subscribe(
            data => (
                this.etudiant=data.etudiant.nom
            ),
            error => {
                console.log(error);
            }
        )
    }


}
```

and here is my providers

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';



    @Injectable()
    export class EtudiantProvider {

    url: string;

    constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello  Provider');
    this.url = "http://localhost/eportfolio/api.php";
  }
  getEtudiant(){
      return  this.http.get(this.url+"?action=getEtudiant").map(res => res.json())
    }

}
```

and this is the page where i need to show data

```
    <ion-list [virtualScroll]="etudiant" [approxItemHeight]="'250px'">
      <ion-item *virtualItem="let etud">
          <ion-avatar item-start id="avatar">
              <p id="letters">AF</p>
          </ion-avatar>
          <h1>{{etud.nom}}</h1>

          <button ion-item clear no-lines>{{etud.nom}}</button>
          <button ion-item clear no-lines>{{etud.prenom}}</button>
      </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Comment: There is no info about your provider but you need to map your response before subscribing.

Comment: there it is i ve update the quastion

Comment: you are mapping json into string and trying to get objects from it. Create an entity class for your response then assign the response.

Comment: how i didn't get it !

Comment: Did you manage to solve it ?

Comment: no i didn't get it ... If you could help me with code !

Answer (score 0):

```
export class etudiantEntity{
  constructor(public nom: string, public prenom: string){}
}
```

create a class like that

and modify your Etudiant

```
export class EtudiantPage {

    public isSearchbarOpened = false;

    etudiant:etudiantEntity; 
...etc
```

This might solve your problem

Comment: Then I'm sorry that I could not help